# ugettext and ugettext_lazy

Tags: python, django, internationalization

Could you explain what principal difference between `ugettext` and `ugettext_lazy`?

When I'm trying to

```py
return HttpResponse(ugettext_lazy("Hello"))
```

I see nothing, but

```py
return HttpResponse(ugettext("Hello"))
```

is working.

Why?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`ugettext` is used to load a translation of a string *right now*.  `ugettext_lazy` returns an object that can eventually be turned into a string.  You need that if the `ugettext_lazy` call is evaluated before the proper locale has been set.

`ugettext_lazy` can be used where you use a Unicode object.  Double-check your HTML output, it might look like this:

```
<django.utils.functional...>
```

and the browser is ignoring it all as an unrecognized tag.

You don't need a lazy translation in this case, because you are immediately using the string.  If you really want to continue with ugettext_lazy for some reason, try this:

```
return HttpResponse(ugettext_lazy("Hello").encode('utf-8'))
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation) for more information.

Comment: I think `ugettext_lazy` is more useful in `models.py`.

Comment: So let me see if I understood you. `ugettext` is useful when you are inside a method or function (like a view for example), or in places that are called after the settings & co have been loaded. `ugettext_lazy` is more useful when wanting to translate class properties and such (as @SergeyOrshanskiy suggested when defining a model or a form) which are loaded when the server starts and need lazy loading. Right?

Comment: @EduardLuca asa e :) It's the same principle as using ``reverse_lazy`` instead of ``reverse``. You may use ``reverse_lazy`` on a class based view to define the ``succes_url`` for example, in which case the reverse shall not be evaluated until it is needed